# Converting snippet from PHP - how to "convert" preg_replace

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code that I'm trying to translate. It seems pretty straightforward but I have no idea how to implement an equivalent preg_replace in c#

```
$sentence = trim(preg_replace('/[¿?¡!«»}،\]\/()[{，、／.,;":0-9]/', ' ', $_GET["sentence"]));
$word = explode(" ", $sentence );
foreach($word as $k => $v) {
    echo $v."; ";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had contributed this answer. Perhaps it can be of use to you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18132398/278976

It will generate source code for many different languages, in addition to teaching you how to use regex better. You can also copy from differently escaped patters, to do the exact conversion that you're asking for.

Using regexbuddy 2.3.0, I get:

```
string ResultString = null;
try {
    ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "[¿?¡!«»}،\\]/()[{，、／.,;\":0-9]", "");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```